# Convert Pandas DateTimeIndex to YYYYMMDD integer?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Is there a preferred way to convert a pandas DateTimeIndex to a column of YYYYMMDD integers?  I need the YYYYMMDD integer format for legacy storage back into a pre-existing SQLite table that assumes dates are integers.

Pandas' **to_sql()** fails with an 'sqlite3.InterfaceError' when using the SQLite flavour and index=True.  Apparently using an SQLalchemy flavor can convert the DateTimeIndex to string, but again I need to have this as an YYYYMMDD integer.

While there seems to be **to_datetime()** and **to_pydatetime()** functions, there doesn't seem to be a **from_datetime()** function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused by what you want. You're trying to convert a `DateTimeIndex` *to* `YYYYMMDD` format; why would you need a `from_datetime` method to do that?

Anyway, you can either map/broadcast the Pandas `Timestamp.strftime` function over it, or use that `to_pydatetime` function that you found and then map the Python `datetime.strftime` function over the resulting array.

> Apparently using an SQLalchemy flavor can convert the DateTimeIndex to string, but again I need to have this as an YYYYMMDD integer.

That's easy. Given a `YYYYMMDD` string, to convert that to an integer, you just call `int` on it—or, if it's in a Pandas/Numpy array, you map or broadcast `int` over it, or, even more simply, just cast its dtype.

For example:

```
>>> dti = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2014-08-31', '2014-09-01'])
>>> pdt = dti.to_pydatetime()
>>> sdt = np.vectorize(lambda s: s.strftime('%Y%m%d'))(pdt)
>>> idt = sdt.astype('I4')
>>> idt
array([20140831, 20140901], dtype=uint32)
```

(I'm not suggesting that this is the most efficient or most readable way to convert a `DateTimeIndex` to an array of `YYYYMMDD` integers, just that it's doable with the functions you appear to already know about, and if this isn't what you want, your question doesn't make sense.)

Comment: Thanks, works for me.  I was just thinking that a `from_datetime` function would help simplify/optimize converting from a `DateTimeIndex` to numpy integer array or other datatype that the user may intend.  TMI I guess -- anyway thanks for the example.

Comment: @bazel: Ah, you mean a `from_datetime` on `np.array`? Well, numpy writes that as `.astype('I4')`, with a few shortcuts like `.asi8()` (you have to specify the `to` type somewhere; you don't have to specify the `from` type because the array already knows what dtype it is…). The problem is that you're trying to convert to a non-standard format. You can just go straight from `Timestamp` to `int`, but then you get nanoseconds from the Unix epoch, not `YYYYMMDD`. You can go from `Timestamp` to `str`, but then you get ISO/RFC format, `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`.